# Azure functions resource reappear shortly after deletion

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

A recently deployed and fully functional Azure Function app is deleted, reported absent, but in a couple of minutes it shows up again in the resource group. What causes its resurrection and how to avoid it?

Here are the details.

An automated integration test has 3 steps.

- Deployment of ~10 resources in an existing empty azure resource group. The deployment includes a function app in consumption plan.
- Functional test of the system that takes ~10 mins.
- Deletion of all resources in the resource group.

In the last deletion step the script first deletes the function app, checks that the resource is no longer reported in the resource group and then lists and deletes all other resources in parallel. Finally it checks that the resource group is empty.

Surprisingly, the last check often fails!

Even more details.

I'm deleting all resources with the same code that checks the resource is absent after the delete operation:

```
            Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $ResourceId -Force | Out-Null
            while (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $ResourceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
                Write-Information "Retry: $resourceId"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $ResourceId -Force | Out-Null
            }
            $ResourceId
```

And here is a sample output:

```
[09/03/2023 22:46:24] Deleting ALL resources in resource group *** in ***...
[09/03/2023 22:46:28] Deleting web apps exekiascanaryghw8sync-runs...
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/exekiascanaryghw8sync-runs
[09/03/2023 22:46:53] Deleting 8 other resources...
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/WestEuropePlan
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/exekiascanaryghw8sync
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/exekiascanaryghw8sync
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/exekiascanaryghw
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/exekiascanaryghw8sync
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/exekiascanaryghw
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/exekiascanaryghw8sync
/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/exekiascanaryghw8sync

Name              : exekiascanaryghw8sync-runs
ResourceGroupName : ***
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Web/sites
Location          : westeurope
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/provid
                    ers/Microsoft.Web/sites/exekiascanaryghw8sync-runs
Tags              : 

Name              : Default1ys
ResourceGroupName : ***
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
Location          : westeurope
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/provid
                    ers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/Default1ys
Tags              : 

Write-Error: D:\a\_temp\11947b94-db88-4a6c-9e1f-6d3ff5b41d40.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  ./cleanup_resource_group.ps1 *** exe …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | [09/03/2023 23:06:28] Resource group is not empty
```

It shows that all resources have been successfully deleted and reported absent, but in ~20 min the final `Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName ***` prints 2 resources. The function app is re-created with the same `ResourceId` in a new automatic `serverFarm` with a strange name `Default1ys`.

After a while these resurrected resources can be safely deleted, but the question is how to avoid the resurrection in the first place?

Comment: Hope your automated script is not scheduled? to run again?

Comment: Is App service plan deleted along with the Function app? The fact that the function app is not being destroyed may be due to another resource managing it. By looking at the "managedBy" attribute of the function app, you may determine whether another resource is in charge of managing the function app. You should get rid of the other resource that is in charge of it if it is, then get rid of the function app.

Comment: One more option is to use Complete mode in your deployment. Here's a sample script- New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
  -TemplateFile "C:\Templates\myTemplate.json" `
  -TemplateParameterFile "C:\Templates\myTemplateParameters.json" `
  -Mode Complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: race condition between resource deletion and Policies remediation.

What is happening?

- Deployment of a function app indirectly triggers a policy assigned by Azure administrators. In my case the policy is to disable TLS versions prior to 1.2.
- In ~20 min after the initial deployment the policy schedules an incremental deployment to the resource group with the function app Id and appropriate resource property.
- My script deletes the resource.
- The policy deployment, instead of just setting the property on an existing resource, creates a new function app with the same name and sets the property on it.

How to avoid this race condition?

- Modify the initial deployment to comply with all the policies. The additional deployments will not be scheduled.
- Per SiddheshiDesai answer use empty deployment in complete mode to clean up the resource group. Not only the code is a cleaner, but it also automatically re-deletes the web site that was re-created by policy deployment.
- (?) List and then monitor policy remediations after initial deployments, although  the remediation is not meant to be a concern of resource creators. Didn't have any experience.

Answer (score 1):

- According to this [**MS Document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/management/delete-resource-group.md) when you delete a resource group, Azure Resource Manager decides which resources to remove first. It uses the following order: all the child (nested) resources are deleted, resources that manage other resources are deleted next, and the remaining resources are deleted after the previous two categories.
- It's possible that another resource is managing the function app in your situation, which is why it isn't being destroyed. By looking at the "managedBy" attribute of the function app, you may determine whether another resource is in charge of managing the function app. If another resource is in charge of it, you should get rid of that resource before getting rid of the function app.
- You can try extending the duration for retries or utilising an alternative technique to delete the resources to get around this problem. In order to verify that all resources are destroyed before the deployment is deemed complete, you can also try utilising the [**"complete" mode**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-complete-mode-deletion.md) for deployment.

**Powershell code with Complete mode as a parameter:-**

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" ` -TemplateFile "C:Template.json" ` -TemplateParameterFile "C:\TemplateParameters.json" ` -Mode Complete
```

***Run the below code to Deploy Function app and Delete it from Azure Portal like below:-***

```
$resourceGroupName = "siliconrg543"  
$functionAppName = "silicon-func58" 
$storageAccountName = "valleystrg095" 
$location = "Australia East" 
$runtime = "dotnet" 
$functionVersion = "3"

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location

New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName -Location $location -SkuName Standard_LRS

New-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Runtime $runtime -Location $location -FunctionsVersion $functionVersion

$resourceGroupName = "siliconrg543" 
$functionAppName = "silicon-func58" 

Remove-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName -Force
Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Force
```

**Function App Deployed like below:-**

[image]

**Resources removed and eventually the resource group also got deleted successfully:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Remove-AzFunctionApp (Az.Functions) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.functions/remove-azfunctionapp?view=azps-10.2.0)

[New-AzFunctionApp (Az.Functions) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.functions/new-azfunctionapp?view=azps-10.2.0)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot apply them in my case. Deleting resource group is not an option due to security hardening: no permissions to create a new resource group as part of automation. I didn't find "managedBy" property on the function app and didn't find any examples when/how the property is used. I do use a workaround to retry deletion in a few minutes, but that doesn't feel like a robust solution. There is still no answer **why this may happen at all?**

Comment: Actually, I completely overlooked the option with empty complete deployment! Will try it and report if it works more reliable that manual deletion of resources.